# can Firefox do ZOOM using CAMERA devices? ({CHROME, EDGE, OPERA} = true, FF = false)

Tags: javascript, firefox

this code allow manage ZOOM (PC, phone, tablet) and work perfect using CHROME, EDGE, OPERA:

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/update-camera-zoom.html

but fail using Firefox multiple versions.

when we see the guts of that code, "the trick" is use

```
track.getCapabilities()
```

when we look in mozilla.org

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Image_Capture_API

they inform **Experimental**, but `track.getCapabilities()` work perfect in chrome, edge, opera...

now is 2023!, exists some code for manage ZOOM camera devices **using Firefox**?

Comment: That page was last updated a few months ago. I suspect the answer for Firefox and Safari is going to be "no".

Comment: This doesn't work even in chrome on a MacBook Pro 2021 (m1). Zoom isn't supported by some devices

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks by fix my `post`. I modify a bit the code and work fine from Android, Linux and W10, W11 using Chrome, Edge, Opera.